# zero clipboard -- calling via function(parameters)

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

please help me to get the code for calling zero-clipboard with the function call - parameters

--for example

```
     function zero_clip_board('text to copy')
     {
         --- function to copy to clipboard via zeroclipboard
     }
```

please if any one aware such a function please post the code for this one thanks in advance

else if any one know to copy the text to the clipboard without flash for all browsers is also welcoming one ---------------------------------- thanks in advance --- i'm waiting for replay's and posts